# Printing out pi as a symbol instead of the numerical value but calculating with the numerical value in the background in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am coding a calculator and I want that the calculator is displaying pi as a symbol and not as the numerical value.

My associated function is

```
function Pi(pi) {
    
  document.getElementById('resultArea').innerHTML += pi
  eval(document.getElementById('resultArea').innerHTML) = x
  x = 3.1415926
    
}
```

And the associated HTML part is:

```
 <td onclick="Pi('π ')" class="changing-button">π</td>
```

InnerHTML is a div container or the part where the results are displayed respectively.

Comment: You should create abstract syntax tree first and then do the calculations. Or just use some regexp to parze everything.

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: That means you should read about it. The project you are trying to do is complicated and it's hard to help you.

Comment: What errors do you see in the browser developer tools console

Comment: "VM56:1 Uncaught ReferenceError:  is not defined
    at eval (eval at Pi (script.js:75:3), <anonymous>:1:1)
    at Pi (script.js:75:3)
    at HTMLTableCellElement.onclick (index.html:59:60)" and "VM58:1 Uncaught ReferenceError:  is not defined
    at eval (eval at Pi (script.js:75:3), <anonymous>:1:1)
    at Pi (script.js:75:3)
    at HTMLTableCellElement.onclick (index.html:59:60)"

Answer (score 0):

I am going to make some assumptions about what you are trying to do.

1. You are trying to get a symbol (e.g. π) to show up in a calculator input/result field.
2. You still want your program to have access to the "number" that said symbol represents for calculations (e.g. 3.14...).

If so, here's a starter paradigm which you can "fill in" to build out the rest of your calculator:

```
/* Calculator operation keys */

const sum = (input) => {
  // ... Sum operation
}
const product = () => {
  // ... Product operation
}

// ... Insert other operations ...

/* Calculator variable keys */

const pi = 3.1415926
const fun = 8008

/* Main logic to calculate values */

const calculate = (memory = []) => {
  // When equals is pressed, calculate the result by executing functions/values from memory array. Returns it in the result div.
  
  let result
  memory.forEach(
    // ...Perform calculations here by looping through memory array... 
  )

  // Return the result into the DOM
  outputDisplay(result,'resultArea')
  return result
}

/* Memory */
const memory = [] // Holds numbers, operations, etc.
let number // Holds most recent number

/* Display input and output via DOM manipulation */

const inputPressed = (value, num = 0) => {
  // Call whenever a button is pressed other than equals (calculate) to update the input display.
  const regex = /[\d.]*/ // Just a sample regex for matching numbers. You will need to update for negative numbers, fractions, etc.
  let figure
  // Define "if" statements (or an object mapping) to connect functions/numbers to their corresponding display figures
  if (value === pi) {
    figure = 'π'  // Displays the figure (e.g. 'π')
    memory.push(num)
    memory.push(value)
  } else if (value === sum) {
    figure = '+'
    memory.push(num)
    memory.push(value)
  } else if (regex.test(value)) { 
    figure = value
    // If input is a number, update the number memory string (Note: there are better ways of doing this but leaving it as string for simplicity.)
    num = `${num}` + `${value}`
  }
  // ...Insert more statements here...

  inputDisplay(figure, 'resultArea')
  return figure
}

const inputDisplay = (character, sel) => {
  // Put the figure in to the DOM (html)
  document.getElementById(sel).innerHTML += character
}

const outputDisplay = (value, sel) => {
  document.getElementById(sel).innerHTML = value
}
```

```
// Returns 'π' and also updates the DOM result area with this symbol. Still retains the number in memory for later operations.  
console.log(inputPressed(pi))
```

It's helpful to keep your calculation operation functions separate from your DOM manipulation.

Comment: First, thank you. I am really new at coding therefore I cannot estimate good if this code is for a whole calculator or not?  to interpreting this code is really though for me but I will try it.

Comment: Happy to help. This is a starting point for building a full (simple) calculator. But, mainly I just wanted to show how you can return a symbol (pi) into the DOM while storing the value. Building a full working calculator is a bit of a tricky first project. Have you looked into https://www.freecodecamp.org/? It may be worth trying some of the simpler exercises there first. Then, returning to this project after you have a good baseline.

Comment: No problem. If this answer helped at all, please feel free to upvote/accept it as it helps me too :). Good luck!